# FB graph api does not return all the data?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use Facebook's graph api to return all the users in a particular closed group. I have access to the group, and can see all the members on facebook.
But when I try the graph api, I get only a subset of the users.

This is what I am trying (in javascript):

`FB.api( '/some-group-id/members?limit=10000&offset=0' , somecallback(){});`

On Facebook, the total members are listed as 11000. But the above query returns only 4500 records, though I have mentioned a limit of 10000. Also the `next` paging url returns an empty data set. Same issue when I use [Facebook's graph explorer tool.](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Is there a restriction on the amount of data Facebook returns? There is a similar issue when I query the `feed` of the group.

Comment: Yea I think /group-id/members have a problem with getting more than 5000 users. I'm guessing there is already a bug report on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs tracking it

Comment: do you know the bug id or url? i would like to track it

Comment: No, that why I didn't link to it. Search and if you don't find it file a new bug

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?  I am running into the same issue and did not see an existing Facebook bug report on it.